# Cultivate snails and maintaining them alive

Tags: agriculture, snail

I found snails in my garden, I want to create a good house for them. I don't really know how to do. Sorry if this is not the good site to ask that but I don't want them to die so I'm trying to be quick.

This is a temporary terrarium for them, is it good ? What do I need to keep them in good health ? What do I need to put in the box ? Is it too small ? I will inquire all about later, I want them first in a safe place.

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: I think you might need to put some large leaves and some water.